# defining a variable to set length of an array is failing but assert and print works

Tags: karate

- `def count = * print response.teams[0].teamMembers.length` throws below error

> com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object
>   with property ['length'] in path $['teams'][0]['teamMembers'] but
>   found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'.
>   This is not a json object
>   according to the JsonProvider:
>   'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

- `print response.teams[0].teamMembers.length` and
- `assert response.teams[0].teamMembers.length == 9`
  are working just fine.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Karate assumes the right-hand-side as Json-Path (which is fine for 90% of the cases). Use parentheses to force JavaScript evaluation when needed.

Try this:

```
def count = (response.teams[0].teamMembers.length)
```

For a detailed explanation, please refer to this section in the documentation: [Karate Expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions)